# Combined hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hover

```
<div class="knoppen">
                <a class="test">HOVER?!</a>
                <span class="icon"><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></span>
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-euro"></i></span>
            </div>

        <div class="sidecontent">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="test"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span><a href="formulieren.html">Formulieren</a></li>
        <li><span class="test"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></span>Contactpersonen</li>
        <li><span class="test"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>Adressen</li>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
div.sidecontent {
        margin-left: -30px;
        display: none;
    }

a.test:hover + div.sidecontent
{
    color: red;
    display: block;
    }
```

Does anyone know why my combined hover doesn't work in this situation?
In my test page it works but when I try to get it working in here.. it just doesn't: I've tried everything but no working results;

Comment: You are using adjacent selector, so the element should be at the same level, and in your case, you are jumping out of the parent element, which won't work, change your markup...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your a.test is not neighbour of div.sidecontent, while CSS selector '+' selects elements that are placed just **immediately after** tag